# Android multi threading UI update

Tags: java, android, multithreading, udp

I'm trying to run a UDP connection with external equipment. I want it to send a message to the equipment every 3 second and read the response. 
I created 3 classes: main, sender and receive.
I open a Runnable for both sender and receive and let them sleep for 3 seconds before continue.

My problem is, when i push the button on the screen, the messages are send and received, however they are not updated on my screen because the update line is not in a loop. How do i tell it to update the screen every 3 second? the code for reading the message and show it, is this:

textViewState.setText(udpReceive.receivedMessage);

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView textViewState;
public static Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    context = getApplicationContext();

}

public void buttonConnect(View v) {

    (new Thread(new udpSender())).start();

    (new Thread(new udpReceive())).start();

    textViewState.setText(udpReceive.receivedMessage);

}


}
```

Class to send a message:

```
public class udpSender implements Runnable {


public void run() {

    while (true) {

        String messageStr = "Hello Android!";
        int server_port = 8888;
        DatagramSocket s = null;
        try {
            s = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InetAddress local = null;
        try {
            local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.159");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int msg_length = messageStr.length();
        byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local, server_port);
        try {
            s.send(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Class to receive message from udp

```
public class udpReceive implements Runnable {

private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 100;
private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 8888;
public static String receivedMessage;

public void run() {


    while (true) {
        String message;
        byte[] lmessage = null;
        lmessage = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
        DatagramPacket packet = null;

        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        try {
            packet = new DatagramPacket(lmessage, lmessage.length);
            socket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            socket.receive(packet);
            message = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());
            receivedMessage = message;
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use Handler to go back to the main thread and then you can update your TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on both of your answers :) Thank you

MainActivity class:

```
public static Handler UIHandler;

static {
    UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

public static void runOnUI(Runnable runnable) {
    UIHandler.post(runnable);
}
```

receive class

```
MainActivity.runOnUI(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         MainActivity.textViewState.setText(message_received);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In any class that is in another thread, try doing this

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable(){
      // your TextView goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the UI thread (main thread) can access UI elements

```
// Your message receiving class
...
message = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());
final String message_received = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());
...

MainActivity.context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.textViewState.setText(message_received);
    }
});
...
```